# How to add html tag from JSon to html table <td>in angular 4

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I'm using angular 4, I have Json like below

```
{"Data":[{"View":"<a href="testurl.com">View</a>"]}
```

I get `Data.View("<a href="testurl.com">View</a>")` to bind with html `<td>`.

but when I try to bind this with html table It shows whole string in html table `<td><a href="testurl.com">View</a></td>` as it is, instead of `<td>`[`View`](http://abcd.com)`</td>`

Comment: I'm expecting output like <td>View</td> but it showing <td><a href="testurl.com">View</td>

Answer (score 0):

try using the innerHTML in the tag as below

```
<td [innerHtml]="Data[0].View"></td>
```

Comment: How I can use it? in scenario like below <table id="tblJobs" class='table table-manage'>
        <thead align="center">
            <tr>
                <th *ngFor="column item of columnName">
                    {{column}}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr id="JobsRow" *ngFor="let data of htmlDataRows">
                <td *ngFor="let column of columnName">
                    {{data[column]}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>